# UDP packet separation

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm creating an UDP service on andorid.
For clarity part of the code copied here:

```
    byte[] message = new byte[1500];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);                    
    socket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.LISTENING_PORT_NUMBER);
    socket.receive(packet);
```

Problem is that I'm receiving UDP packets continuously.
For example packet #1 (250 byte long), packet #2 (182 byte long), packet #3 (403 byte long) etc...

I need to get and process the separate UDP packets which has variable length.
According to UDP protocol specification UDP packets has message boundaries defined.
However I found no solution in Java which can separate UDP packets.

In my current solution I have to define the packet length which I must read, but I don't know the packet length before I receive it.

Am I missing a point?

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for both Tobias and shazin both are correct answers. Sad I cant's mark two answer as correct.

The `socket.receive(packet);` will receive until the UDP packet boundary, subsequent packages can be read with another `socket.receive(packet);`.
 
My problem should be that during the process of the first message the arrived further messages are not processed because of synchronous processing, now I'll pass the message processing to an async task and hopefully will be able to catch all arrived packets in time.

Comment: I believe whatever you set is rewritten when you receive the packet. Hold on 'till I pick up the documentation.

Comment: why on earth would you use udp ? tcp has packet sequence and collating insurance

Comment: @njzk2 realtime streaming data where you prefer timeliness over reliability.

Comment: @njzk2: as per customer requirement, customer is running a private network and communicates with UDP packets with all devices.
(My first reaction was the same as yours at the first time I heard)

Comment: Can you paste the corresponding client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but a `DatagramPacket` is *one* packet that is sent. It has the `getLength()` and `getOffset()` methods require to get to the data. I believe that there is also a `getData()` that returns the data sent.

Here you have a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) That can help you further.

Comment: Hello, DatagramPacket constructor needs the length parameter to be provided, so getLength() will return the buffer length

Comment: That is the maximum length, not the length of the packet.

Comment: Ok you are right, my problem is that the subsequent packets are lost and not processed by the app, because of the synchronous processing.

Comment: Just copy the data into a [BlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or similar in one thread, and process them one-by-one in another. Give the reveiving thread high prio.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know the packet length before hand. You can define a maximum boundary bytes array based on the data you may be receiving. 2048 byte array is recommended.

```
byte[] message = new byte[2048];
```

Even if you have variable length in incoming message packets, you can use the following code to receive

```
byte[] message = new byte[2048];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);                    
socket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.LISTENING_PORT_NUMBER);
socket.receive(packet);
String data = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
```

getData and getLength methods can be used to determine the size of the received packet.

Comment: You are taking for granted that the offset is 0. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau, what do you mean?

Comment: The 0 in `new String()` should be `packet.getOffset()`, right?